Does the nums array make a deep copy of letters[2:5] = ['C', 'D', 'E']?
I am learning shallow v.s. deep copying a list in Python. I learned that there're two ways to create copies that have the original values unchanged and only modify the new values or vice versa.  They're shallow copy and deep copy.
Besides Copy.copy() and Copy.deepcopy(), I learned slice operators can be use for shallow and deep copying a list.  From the Python official documentation, I was able to find information that doing correct_rgba = rgba[:], correct_rgba makes a shallow copy of rgba.
Example 1.
rgba = ["Red", "Green", "Blue", "Alph"]
correct_rgba = rgba[:]
correct_rgba[-1] = "Alpha"
correct_rgba  # ["Red", "Green", "Blue", "Alpha"]
rgba  # ["Red", "Green", "Blue", "Alph"]

However, I couldn't find information to confirm whether Assignment to Slices is a deep copy. Here is an example found on the same Python documentation.
Example 2.
letters = ['a', 'b', 'c', 'd', 'e', 'f', 'g']
letters[2:5] = ['C', 'D', 'E']
letters  # ['a', 'b', 'C', 'D', 'E', 'f', 'g']
letters[:] = []
letters  # []

My questions:
(1) Does letters[2:5] deep copy ['C', 'D', 'E']?  Does letters[:] deep copy []?
(2) How do I test to find out whether a list is a shallow or deep copy?

Does this answer your question? What is the difference between shallow copy, deepcopy and normal assignment operation?

You could use lists instead of strings and check their ids, as in this answer to test for shallow vs deep copies.

Deep or shallow copy makes no difference for immutable types like strings.

Assignment to slices is neither shallow nor deep, there's nothing special about it. Assignment from slices produces a shallow copy because you are assigning values (the result of evaluating the slice), not references... but this values can be references themselves.

Let's break down your questions and concerns:
(1) Does letters[2:5] deep copy ['C', 'D', 'E']?  Does letters[:] deep copy []?
No, neither of these operations performs a deep copy.

letters[2:5] = ['C', 'D', 'E'] is an assignment to a slice of the original list. It replaces the elements at indices 2, 3, and 4 with the new values, but it doesn't create a new copy of the list. The original list is modified in place.
letters[:] = [] is also an assignment to a slice, but this time it replaces the entire list with an empty list. Again, this modifies the original list, it doesn't create a new copy.

(2) How do I test to find out whether a list is a shallow or deep copy?
To determine whether a list is a shallow or deep copy, you can use the following methods:
Shallow copy:

Use the id() function to check if the original list and the copied list have the same memory address. If they do, it's a shallow copy.
Modify the original list and check if the copied list is affected. If it is, it's a shallow copy.

Example:
original_list = [[1, 2], [3, 4]]
shallow_copy = original_list[:]
print(id(original_list) == id(shallow_copy))  # True
original_list[0][0] = 10
print(shallow_copy)  # [[10, 2], [3, 4]] (affected by original list)

Deep copy:

Use the id() function to check if the original list and the copied list have different memory addresses. If they do, it might be a deep copy.
Modify the original list and check if the copied list is not affected. If it's not, it's likely a deep copy.

Example:
import copy
original_list = [[1, 2], [3, 4]]
deep_copy = copy.deepcopy(original_list)
print(id(original_list) != id(deep_copy))  # True
original_list[0][0] = 10
print(deep_copy)  # [[1, 2], [3, 4]] (not affected by original list)

Keep in mind that these methods are not foolproof, and there might be edge cases where they don't accurately determine whether a copy is shallow or deep. However, they should give you a good indication in most cases.

I don't know the exact answers off hand, but the important question is really #2: "How do I test to find out whether a list [is] a shallow or deep copy?"
The is keyword tests for identity (different from equality). The expression a is b evaluates to True if the variables a and b reference the same object. To find out if a list l2 is a deep or shallow copy of list l1, do an is comparison between the elements.
l1 = [MyObject()]
l2 = l1[:]
print(l1[0] is l2[0])

I would caution you against using primitive data types within the list, as they are subject to unpredictable optimizations. For example, last I checked, two integer variables between 0 and 255 always have the same identity. I don't know whether strings behave at all similarly.

String literals comprised of ASCII characters that are legal in variable names, along with all single character ASCII strings, are singletons as implementation details of CPython, as is the empty string.

There is a mix-up of terms:

The question seems to be whether assigning to a slice assigns a reference to the original list or not. Here is one way to test this:

    >>> x = ['C', 'D', 'E']
    >>> y=['a', 'b','c','d','e']
    >>> y[2:5]=x
    >>> y
    ['a', 'b', 'C', 'D', 'E']
    >>> x[0]='XX'
    >>> y
    ['a', 'b', 'C', 'D', 'E']
    >>> x
    ['XX', 'D', 'E']


Is the assignment doing a deep copy of the list, or copying a reference of the original items. This can't be tested with a list of primitive types, which can't be changed without referencing a different value, but we need things which are mutable, so they can be changed without changing the reference:

    >>> z=[[1,3],4]
    >>> y[0:2]=z
    >>> y
    [[1, 3], 4, 'C', 'D', 'E']
    >>> z[0][0]='XX'
    >>> z[1]='OO'
    >>> z
    [['XX', 3], 'OO']
    >>> y
    [['XX', 3], 4, 'C', 'D', 'E']


Not sure what you mean by "are always copied".  Even primitive types use references.

@MarkRansom You're right, removed that part. Mutable is really what I wanted.

@kabanus, I got ['a', 'b', 'A', 'B', 'C'] printing y in your first ex, and the following code are affected.

@LEDFantom Oops, the first line is wrong. The only one I didn't copy paste... Fixed. I think the point stands though.
